# R - Predicted variables not included in linear regression graph

Tags: r, linear-regression

Here's the relevant code snippet. How do I get the predicted variables to display in the plot?

```
df <- data.frame(X = 2010:2022, Y = c(11539282, 11543332, 11546969, 11567845, 11593741, 11606027, 11622554, 11658609, rep(NA, 5)))

model.1 <- lm(formula = Y ~ X, data = df)
predict(object = model.1, newdata = df)
plot(X, Y, ylim=c(11500000,11750000))
lines(sort(X), fitted(model.1)[order(X)])
```

Comment: You didn't assign the output of `predict()` to anything so how can it be plotted? I realize (from your previous q — which is quite literally a content precursor to this one — and this one) that you're super-new to R but some basic research into R fundamentals (if the course is not providing it) is going to be necessary to gain independent proficiency.

Comment: Thanks for that feedback. You're correct, I've never used R and current course is not providing much direction.  Certainly open to suggestions for self teaching materials.

Comment: Click on the "r" tag at the bottom of your question, go to the "info" tab & the world is your oyster. Also, I have no idea who downvoted but I'm going to tick it back up to 0. this is a legitimate question with reproducible code.

Comment: Thanks for your help! BTW your 'clue' about not assigning the output of predict() was exactly what I needed.  I assigned it to a new variable and now the values are in my plot.  :-)

Comment: Nice! Definitely code that up as an answer! We can up vote it and you can accept it after some waiting period! That's !

Comment: I stand corrected, while I did get new points on my scatter plot, they were not the values. Apparently I was creating a new plot with evenly distributed values.

Answer (score 2):

Make these changes:

1. when creating the model use `na.action = na.exclude`
2. use the formula methods for `plot` and `lines`
3. use  `fitted(model.2)` as the predicted values
4. no sorting is needed as `X` is already sorted

giving this code:

```
model.2 <- lm(Y ~ X, df, na.action = na.exclude)
plot(Y ~ X, df)
lines(fitted(model.2) ~ X, df)
```

or use `abline` in which case this shorter code can be used:

```
model.3 <- lm(Y ~ X, df)
plot(Y ~ X, df)
abline(model.3)
```

In either case we get this output:

[image: screenshot]

### Added

Based on clarification in the comments we could do this (or if you want an even wider range try `ylim = extendrange(pred, f = .10)` to extend the range by 10%, say, on either side).

```
pred <- predict(model.3, df)
plot(Y ~ X, df, ylim = range(pred))
lines(pred ~ X, df)
```

giving:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your input! Your graphic also excludes the values for years 2018 through 2022.

Comment: When I try that, it still doesn't include the new values on the scatter plot.  Did you get them?

Comment: The predicted line goes all the way to 2022.  See **Added** section and image.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.  Now I can sleep :-)